# Query produces no records for a field when adding more than one condition to JOIN or WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query returns lots of records and the field DT_Cancelled has all values populated with a timestamp. This is expected (DT_Created and Upgraded are all null right now as expected too):

```
SELECT 
        co.email,
        co.id,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 581 THEN my.data END AS DT_Created,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN my.data END AS DT_Upgraded,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3014 THEN my.lastmod END AS DT_Cancelled
    FROM 
        ex_emails.cid208 co
        INNER JOIN ex_emails.my208 my ON my.eid = co.id 
        WHERE my.my_id = 3014
        GROUP BY email
```

However, the following query produces a results set where DT_Cancelled has all NULL values.

```
SELECT 
        co.email,
        co.id,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 581 THEN my.data END AS DT_Created,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN my.data END AS DT_Upgraded,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3014 THEN my.lastmod END AS DT_Cancelled
    FROM 
        ex_emails.cid208 co
        INNER JOIN ex_emails.my208 my ON my.eid = co.id 
        WHERE (my.my_id = 581 OR my.my_id = 3347 OR my.my_id = 3014) # Here is the altered line
        GROUP BY email
```

I then tried this but got the same result: DT_Cancelled was all NULL values.

```
SELECT 
        co.email,
        co.id,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 581 THEN my.data END AS DT_Created,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN my.data END AS DT_Upgraded,
        CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3014 THEN my.lastmod END AS DT_Cancelled
    FROM 
        ex_emails.cid208 co
        INNER JOIN ex_emails.my208 my ON my.eid = co.id AND (my.my_id = 581 OR my.my_id = 3347 OR my.my_id = 3014) 
        GROUP BY email
```

I had expected to see all the records I saw from the above query. Why have I lost them all with this modification?

Comment: Can you post some sample data to show what rows it fails for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` is bad.

When you GROUP BY, you need to add all fields that are not aggregating with a SUM or MAX or AVG or what-have-you. MySQL allows this wrong query to run (which is infuriatingly stupid), even though the SQL is wrong and mySQL is trying to guess at what you mean. Fix your `GROUP BY` by grouping everything with `GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5` and run each query again. If that doesn't solve it, then perhaps we'll probably need some example data.

Comment: Ach! Yes, it is infuriating. I've only recently started using MySQL  (Learned SQL on Teradata)and am used to be told a query won't run unless all non aggregated fields are in the group by clause. That sorted it though.

Comment: I live in Teradata currently, and I'm driven mad by MySQL acceptance of bad GROUP BY statements... who knows what it's going to do when you leave off non-aggregated fields.. It's completely bonkers.

Comment: Well, so far my colleague has got me ordering subqueries by ASC or DESC on certain fields in order to select the first value MySQL comes across when using group by without all the non aggregated selected fields in it. That was a mouthful. Seems could useful but MySQL may cause me to become a poor SQL analyst.